# how to do a SELECT in SQLite with a range of dates from datetime string to a UNIX timestamp?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, unix-timestamp

Hi I have a database SQLite with a table "data" with the column "time@timestamp" that is a REAL for example 1669729394.792
So I have to select a range of data using 2 dates (start date and end date) written by the operator in human datetime format (ex. 2022-11-29) and extract all my data
somehow I should convert my date from standard format to UNIX timestamp

I tried like this but it doesn't work for me:

`SELECT * FROM data  WHERE date([time@timestamp]) BETWEEN  CAST(strftime('%s', '2022-11-29') AS REAL) AND  CAST(strftime('%s', '2022-11-30') AS REAL)`

Answer (score 0):

The function [`date()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) with a numeric parameter and no modifiers considers the numeric value as a [Julian day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) and returns that date in the text format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

But your datetime values are not Julian days, they are [unix timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and you can transform them to a readable date format `YYYY-MM-DD` with the modifier `'unixepoch'`:

```
date([time@timestamp], 'unixepoch')
```

After that you can directly compare the result to any date in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` and no casting is needed:

```
SELECT * 
FROM data  
WHERE date([time@timestamp], 'unixepoch') BETWEEN '2022-11-29' AND '2022-11-30'
```

Or, keep the value of `[time@timestamp]` as it is and transform the 2 date boundaries to unix timestamps:

```
SELECT * 
FROM data  
WHERE [time@timestamp] BETWEEN strftime('%s', '2022-11-29') AND strftime('%s', '2022-11-30')
```

Or, if your version of SQLite is 3.38.0+:

```
SELECT * 
FROM data  
WHERE [time@timestamp] BETWEEN unixepoch('2022-11-29') AND unixepoch('2022-11-30')
```